# only download new files (wget -N) in python

Tags: python, wget

I am trying to use a python package to download new files. All I can do is download like

```
outdir = ""
url = ""
filename = wget.download(url, out=outdir)
```

but how can I tell wget to only download new files?
In the command line I did it with

```
wget -N url
```

which only downloads the new files. The python package wget does not seem to have any equivalent to the -N flag? 
Does anybody know whether there is a way to do this with wget for python or is there another python package which can do that?

Comment: Are you using Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping) library you are talking about, then it is built on top of urllib rather than being a wrapper around `wget`. So you have a couple options.

- If you want the -N functionality with this library you'll have to implement it yourself. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping) is how `wget` determines what is a new file. There are 3 different techniques that are used to accomplish this. It looks for file names that do not already exist. For HTTP it looks for a Last-Modified header. For FTP it uses a LIST command then tries to parse the output as if the output were the same output as a `ls -l` command.
- If you running this script on a system with a `wget` executable in the path then you can use subprocess.

Here is the code for that.

```
import subprocess
url = ''
subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-N', url])
```